# I want to create an e-learning website

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

I want to create an e-learning website and host it. (Maybe after some time I want to add forms.)

These are the things I know: java, jsp, servlet, html (not guru, almost beginner).

I don't have experience in creating websites, I did my college project using jsp,servlet and jdbc.

What are the things or technology I need to know before creating website.

Is it possible to create a website by one person?

Comment: Hi Viswa, in it's current format, your question is pretty difficult to answer in a way that will have value for yourself and the community. Just briefly - you will need to know html (to display information), css (to layout and style your website) and possible javascript for any further frontend development. You'll then need a backend language to handle things like form processing - Java/JSP are sufficient, though it might be easier for you to start with PHP if you are not comfortable with programming. And yes, lots of websites are created and managed by just one person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Moodle](http://moodle.org) is an open source PHP application for e-learning websites. One person could use that to create what you want.